# How search row num partition by user

Tags: sql, presto

How to write sql in presto？
Here is my sql：

```
    select
t.user_id,t.loguni_datetime,t.page_type,t.action_type,t.tab_name,
 row_number()   OVER (PARTITION BY t.user_id
                    ORDER BY log_time) AS rnk
from datamart_iptv_shyd_sh.f_visit_click_detail t 
where t."year"='2019' and t."month"='07' and t."day"='10'
and t.page_type is not null
order by t.user_id,log_time
```

and I get this：

[image]

but I want to get partition by userid and page_type like this：
[image]

the rnk aways begin with '/epg/portal'

thanks~

Comment: Your query refers to `year`, `month`, and `day`, and yet these are not in your result set.  You say to partition by `page_type`, but `action_type` seems more appropriate.  The question is very unclear.

Comment: sorry，my English ispoor，I want to use userid partition, then pagetype for time sorting, encounter portl page to reorder.The result like the red words in the second picture。

Answer (score 0):

add t.page_type on partition and use `dense_rank`

```
select
t.user_id,t.loguni_datetime,t.page_type,t.action_type,t.tab_name,
 dense_rank()   OVER (PARTITION BY t.user_id,t.page_type
                    ORDER BY log_time) AS rnk
from datamart_iptv_shyd_sh.f_visit_click_detail t 
where t."year"='2019' and t."month"='07' and t."day"='10'
and t.page_type is not null
order by t.user_id,log_time
```